# Re arranging specific rows to columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a schema with the following columns and rows from  [dbo].[obs]

| NIN | SECTION | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CM86029 | Reg | X00 |
| CM86029 | EmNumber | 807032 |
| CM86029 | Employee | PETER |
| CM84038 | Reg | X01 |
| CM84038 | EmpNumber | 807033 |
| CM84038 | Employee | EMMANUEL |

i have tried to get the contents in the  section   pickup values from the Result column to get the following ouput using unpivot query.

| NIN | Reg | EmNumber | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CM86029 | X00 | 807032 | PETER |
| CM84038 | X01 | 807033 | EMMANUEL |

the result i have got are all different from what i need to achieve. below is my code.

```
SELECT    NIN, RegistrationNumber,  EmployeeNumber, SupplierNumber
FROM      [dbo].[obs]
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
        ('RegistrationNumber','EmployeeNumber','SupplierNumber','ss'),

         (Result,Result,Result,Result) 

 ) c (RegistrationNumber,EmployeeNumber,SupplierNumber,value);
```

This is the output i get instead.

| NIN | Reg | EmNumber | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CM860291035WVE | RegistrationNumber | EmployeeNumber | SupplierNumber |
| CM860291035WVE | Teachers/Doctors | Teachers/Doctors |  |
| CM860291035WVE | RegistrationNumber | EmployeeNumber | SupplierNumber |
| CM860291035WVE | 000000000807032 | 000000000807032 | 000000000807032 |
| CM860291035WVE | RegistrationNumber | EmployeeNumber | SupplierNumber |

Comment: You want to *pivot*, not unpivot.

Comment: how tho, having no field to SUM()

Comment: Then you would use expressions like `MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'EmNumber' THEN result END)`. You can check the link I closed your question with for a lot of examples. If you get stuck somewhere while implementing the new solution, please come back :)